# Linkified textview invisible in RTL

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, right-to-left

I'm facing some problems with RTL support on a linkified TextView. My code is as follows:

```
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.where);
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setAutoLinkMask(0);
            textView.setText(location);
            if (!Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS |
                    Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES | Linkify.MAP_ADDRESSES)) {
                Linkify.addLinks(textView, mWildcardPattern, "geo:0,0?q=");
            }
            textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    try {
                        return v.onTouchEvent(event);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        // ignore
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

And for my TextView:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/where"
        style="@style/ViewEventStyle.FontSmall.Link"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/event_view_no_margin"
        android:textDirection="locale"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

The TextView is invisible when a RTL language is set, but visible as normal for any other language. 
The strange this is also that if I touch the location of the TextView it becomes visible and starts the specified activity (from linkify) and when I go back the TextView is always visible. If I change the textDirection element to ltr it's visible as it should, but displayed from the wrong direction. I've tried invalidating, requestinglayout, changing textcolors, setting visibility, making sure it has enough space, getting the text and everything is as it should except that it's invisible. The style doesn't contain anything related to other than setting the size of the text

Anyone with any hints? This is on a phone running api 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, the problem was that when single line was true the textview would be invisible, but if I changed it to maxLines=1 instead it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if it's still relevant nor if it's connected (i'd post it as a comment except i don't have enough reputation - yet :) but I had quite a lot of problems with RTL, some of them similar, when running on API 17. Buttons disappearing, etc. Try running it on 4.3 ? 
I can't tell for sure that's the problem, because for me the issue was in the layouts: apparently,in 4.2.2=17, if there a Left and a Start element, they're both somehow taken into account, so you have to leave one out, but in your xml snippet there's none. Maybe in the rest of the file - in which case try this too (if you run only on >=17, use Start/End, otherwise you'll have to duplicate layouts)